# JSF template overriding don't work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

My main template:

```
<h:body>


    <div id="top" class="top">
        <ui:insert name="top">Top</ui:insert>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="left">
            <ui:insert name="left"></ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="left_content">
            <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:body>
```

my client template(that should override the parts above):

```
<body>

    <ui:composition template="./mainTemplate.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="top">
            top 123
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="left">
            left 123
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="content">
            content 123
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</body>
```

the template is loading using the default values, thus is not overriding, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not loading your client template, If your `mainTemplate.xhtml` is in the root of your application, just use it like this: `template="/mainTemplate.xhtml"` without the `"."`

Also, Be sure that you are using the correct namespace for faclet declaration, which is for your case (based on your question tags, I assumed you use JSF 2.2 ):

```
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets
```